# Regex to extract first 5 digit+character from last hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract first 5 character+digit from last hyphen.
Here is the example

1. String -- X008-TGa19-ER751QF7

Output -- X008-TGa19-ER751

2. String -- X002-KF13-ER782cPU80

Output -- X002-KF13-ER782

My attempt -- I could manage to take element from the last -- `(\w+)[^-.]*$`

But now how to take first 5, then return my the entire value as the output as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally repeat a `-` and 1+ word chars from the start of the string. Then match the last `-` and match 5 word chars.

```
^\w+(?:-\w+)*-\w{5}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Math 1+ word chars
- `(?:-\w+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ word chars
- `-\w{5}` Match `-` and 5 word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vitYhw/1)

```
import re

regex = r"^\w+(?:-\w+)*-\w{5}"
s = ("X008-TGa19-ER751QF7\n"
    "X002-KF13-ER782cPU80")
    
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['X008-TGa19-ER751', 'X002-KF13-ER782']
```

---

Note that `\w` can also match `_`.

If there can also be other character in the string, to get the first 5 digits or characters except `_` after the last hyphen, you can match word characters without an underscore using a negated character class `[^\W_]{5}`

Repeat that 5 times while asserting no more underscore at the right.

```
^.*-[^\W_]{5}(?=[^-]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGgkVg/1)

Answer (score 1):

`(\w+-\w+-\w{5})`  seems to capture what you're asking for.
Example:
https://regex101.com/r/PcPSim/1

Comment: This works too, but I choose to mark the second one because it helped to setup the python part too ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are open for *non-regex* solution, you can use this which is based on *splitting*, *slicing* and *joining* the strings:

```
>>> my_str = "X008-TGa19-ER751QF7"

>>> '-'.join(s[:5] for s in my_str.split('-'))
'X008-TGa19-ER751'
```

Here I am splitting the string based on hyphen `-`, slicing the string to get at max five chars per sub-string, and joining it back using `str.join()` to get the string in your desired format.

Answer (score 1):

`^(.*-[^-]{5})[^-]*$`
Capture group 1 is what you need

https://regex101.com/r/SYz9i5/1

Explanation

```
^(.*-[^-]{5})[^-]*$
^                    Start of line
 (                   Capture group 1 start
  .*                 Any number of any character
    -                hyphen
     [^-]{5}         5 non-hyphen character
            )        Capture group 1 end 
             [^-]*   Any number of non-hyphen character
                  $  End of line
```

---

Another simpler one is

`^(.*-.{5}).*$`

This should be quite straight-forward.

This is making use of behaviour greedy match of first `.*`, which will try to match as much as possible, so the `-` will be the last one with at least 5 character following it.
https://regex101.com/r/CFqgeF/1/